# How do I create/encode a string with a specific encoding in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, encoding, iso-8859-1

How do I create/encode a string with a specific encoding in C#/.Net framework? For example, I would like to make a string which uses the Western European ISO 8859-1 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

C#/.Net/.NetCore Framework(s) use the UTF-16 encoding (i.e. any string you create will be this encoding). Which is found under Encoding.Unicode (but not necessarily UTF-16 for everyone...).

Thus you need to convert your string to the desired encoding. Note that this approach/code is only if you have created your own string, otherwise you have to take a different approach if you got the string/text from somewhere else like a file.

`Encoding westernEuropeanIso8859 = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
Encoding utf16CSharpDefault = Encoding.Unicode;
byte[] utfBytes = utf16CSharpDefault.GetBytes(vExp);
byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf16CSharpDefault, westernEuropeanIso8859, utfBytes);
string stringWithDesiredEncoding = westernEuropeanIso8859.GetString(isoBytes);`

Comment: I found this out by combining several questions/websites and thought it would be more useful to have a brief and clear answer